# Can you recommend a book on Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, resource-recommendations

I'm looking for a book on Inkscape. This may be a subjective question but I'm looking for a book that ideally complies with this criteria:

- For the more advanced user. I don't mind if it has some basic stuff but I already know how to draw a star and rectangle ;)
- Explaining design concepts and theoretical background is okay or would actually be good.
- Some Inkscape "programming" would be great! To see how a vector graphic program works (basically, the math behind it) would be nice.
- Ideally it shows the full potential of Inkscape and its tools. I don't want a full guide with examples for each and every option but an overview and what-else there is and possibly a brief introduction on how to use it would be nice.
- Ideally written by someone of the community and/or a open source supporter.

To summarize I would like a book to learn something new from and not a step to step guide to be followed on the computer screen. Something that can also be useful without a computer at hand where you would think "Oh, this looks great, didn't know that was possible... gonna try it tomorrow!".

And yes, I'm looking for a real book. I know that there are thousands of tutorials online but I *really* like to have a physical book in front of me.

Comment: I know the Book https://www.amazon.de/Inkscape-Umfassendes-Handbuch-gro%C3%9Fem-Praxisteil/dp/3826690346 from Sirko Kemter which comes close to your needs but is in German and for the last version. Programming and math behind is not a topic. AFAIK there is no English translation.

Comment: I also recommend you [A Guide to Inkscape](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/), from Tavmjong Bah, also freely available in the web version.